# How to Display .PHP in lytebox

Tags: php, html, css

Run into a bit of a snag and wondered if anyone could help, im trying to display a forum in a pop yp lytebox but i can not get .php extensions to load, html will load fine.
I will use www.example.com/forum/index.php as an example (as my url is similar)

Here is the code i am using.

```
`<a href="http://www.example.com/forum/index.php" rel="lyteframe" title="MY FORUM" rev="width:100%; height:100%; scrolling: no;"><img class="img-circle" src="images/Service3.png" alt="service 3"></a>`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is your php code? and can you post the whole file?

Comment: There is no php code, im purely trying to display a web forum in the lytebox, the lytebox is made up of html, css, js the address of the forum is www.example.com.forum/index.php , again if i put in html pages they load fine, for example if i changed the a href to http://www.bbc.com that loads with no issues.

Comment: The lytebox is basically a posh pop up iframe of sorts.

Comment: I am getting a Unknown host error "Description: Unable to locate the server named "www.example.com.forum" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again."

Comment: Thats because its example.com mate, i.e i have not given the url address :) the website i want to display in the lytebox isnt the issue, its something within the lytebox that will not display php pages and only html page. Appreciate you taking a look though mate.

Comment: Admin close this topic please, found the issue, it wouldnt display the php page on preview locally through dreamweaver though it would html pages, however once i uploaded it to my webserver wwwroot it displays fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, although it does not display in preview mode, the lytebox does display the php when the file is online, once i uploaded the website to wwwroot or public_html and visit the site, the lytebox displays the page correctly, im not sure why this is, but it is certainly a fix, im presuming it cant not display php when in local preview even if it links to another site.
So in short although preview will not display the php, sending to live will.